# how to put the code in comments

Tags: support, comments, code-formatting

I many times tried that four space(bar)s before and after the code. But I never succeed. Can one say how to put the code in the comments.

Comment: Here I am typing the code with spacebars. And see how it prints
    #include<iostream>

Comment: Use backticks, just like you do in the post body.

Comment: `This is in backticks to test James's theory`

This is not in backticks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the comment system and comments work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-does-the-comment-system-and-comments-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within comments you can use backticks (`) which on most keyboards is on the same key as the tilde (~)

you can use this in both posts and comments by wrapping the code section in `backticks`.